# Minimum datetime of today

Tags: mariadb

I need to fetch the first time in the day that a user logs in.

I have a table that logs every users login in the system (DATETIME). Problem is that every single log is inserted in the table

**for example this query gives me the last time they have logged.**

```
SELECT user, MAX(date) FROM table GROUP BY user;
fizz        2020-01-15 08:44:59
buzz        2020-01-15 08:43:11
john        2020-01-15 08:41:24
smith       2020-01-15 08:38:37
pignon      2020-01-15 08:38:06
legolas     2020-01-15 08:35:08
```

But what i need is the first time they have logged TODAY so,

the minimum date of today

***I have tried EXTRACT but it seems i cannot get what i want. Please help !***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` clause to limit the rows to today which you can get with the function [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):

```
SELECT user, MIN(date) 
FROM table 
WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY user;
```

Comment: To run faster, have `INDEX(usager, date)` _and_ change to `WHERE date >= CURDATE()`.